# Out of memory error while calculating sum of multiples of 3 and 5 in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, sum, out-of-memory

This is my code:

```
import Data.Bits

main = print . sum . takeWhile( < 200000) $ multSum 999

multSum m = 3 : multiples [6..m]  where
    multiples (p:xs) 
       | ((p `mod` 3 == 0)  || (p `mod` 5 == 0)) = p : multiples([p..m])
       | otherwise = p : xs
```

> Error: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`multSum` isn't doing what you think it is. Try debugging it directly:

```
*Main> take 20 $ multSum 999
[3,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
```

Answer (score 4):

`multSum` returns the infinite list `[3,6,6,6,6...]` for all arguments, thus it never exceeds 200000 and so the sum you request can't be printed.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
mults35 m = multiples [3..m] .....
  ............
  ....| ......    = p : multiples xs
  ... | otherwise =     multiples xs
```

there will be one more thing for you to add there. Try this, and you'll see.

Comment: The error I get is: prob1: prob1.hs:(6,5)-(8,33): Non-exhaustive patterns in function multiples

Comment: @Hick exactly! Your definition is: `multiples (p:xs) = ...`. I.e. it receives non-empty list, with the head element `p` and the rest of them `xs`. But what if it receives non-empty list, `[]`? Is that clause defined somewhere in your program? If not, add it!

Comment: @Hick you add the new clause thus: `multiples [] = ...` It should return the same type of result as the previous clause. Its return value is `p: ...`, i.e. it is a list. So the new clause must return a list, too.

Comment: In this case, shouldn't the final case be: p == m = p : multiples 0  the one where there is no array left to traverse anymore? If no, then I'm completely confused.

Comment: @Hick the "multiples" receives a list. It is either a non-empty list `(p:xs)`, or an empty list `[]`. But, we know what list is it consuming - *we* gave it that list - it is the list `[3..m]`. So yes, the last element in that list will be `p`, and the list at that time will be a singleton list (i.e. with only one elemt inside) `(p:xs)` where `xs=[]`. We could stop processing when we detect that we're on the last element, too, yes, that's another way to code this. That way we'll never hit on an empty list case. So, we'l have to add a new sub-clause to the non-empty clause, above the two. (contd

Comment: @Hick and it will read `| p==m = ...`. So what goes inside? First we must check, whether `p` belongs or not, and that means we have to duplicate the tests. And then, instead of writing `multiples xs` - we know that `xs=[]` - we know it's `multiples []` - here we decide what it is: an *empty* list. Nothing to process further; must stop; list ends with an empty list: `[1,2,3] == 1:2:3:[] = (1:(2:(3:[])))`. --- but, notice two things: A. we must dulicate the test whether to include `p` or not; B. this clause goes above all the rest, so will be checked for each elt in list. It's inefficient. (cont

Comment: @Hick OTOH we already check whether the list is non-empty: we match it with `(p:xs)`. So if it's not - if it's empty - doesn't need any additional tests. So we we leave the first clause as is, and add a new one, for [] lists - we can just give it an answer: an empty list.

Comment: do you have any more questions here? :)